# Xpath query assistance nested anchor href extract

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

Here is my code:

```
$text = '<div class="cgus_post"><a href="?p=15055">Hello</a></div>';
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($text);
$classname = 'cgus_post';
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$nodes = $finder->query('//div[class="cgus_post"]//@href');
```

I'm trying to get the href text for an anchor link within the div `cgus_post`. What's wrong with my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably a missing "@"

```
'//div[@class="cgus_post"]//@href'
```

Comment: `@href` attribute should be inside the tag `a`. But how is this `//@href` will work,without selecting the `a` element nodes ?

Comment: Ohh! new lessons for me.. *+1* ..Yes it worked that way.. Thanks for that! :)

Answer (score 0):

XPath is incorrect. It should be:

```
//div[@class="cgus_post"]/a
```

Then `$nodes` will be a list of all `<a>` tags inside a `<div class="cgus_post">`, and you get their hrefs with

```
foreach($nodes as $node) {
   $href = $node->getAttribute('href');
}
```